# Python: count values within defined intervals

Tags: python, count, numbers, intervals

I import data from a CSV which looks like this:

```
3.13
3.51
3.51
4.01
2.13
1.13
1.13
1.13
1.63
1.88
```

What I would like to do now is to **COUNT** the values within those intervals:
0-1, 1-2, 2-3, >3

So the result would be

```
0-1: 0
1-2: 5
2-3: 1
>3: 4
```

Apart from this main task I would like to calculate the outcome into percent of total numbers (e.g. 0-1: 0%, 1-2: 50%,...)

I am quite new to Python so I got stuck in my attemps solving this thing. Maybe there is a predefined function for solving this I don't know of?

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

**+++ UPDATE: +++**

Thanks for all the replies.
I have testes a bunch of them but I kind of doing something wrong with reading the CSV-File I guess. Refering to the code snippets using a,b,c,d for the differnt intervalls these variables always stay '0' for me.

Here is my actual code:

```
import csv

a=b=c=0
with open('winter.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        if row in range(0,1):
            a += 1
        elif row in range (1,2):
            b += 1

print a,b
```

I also converted all values in the CSV to Integers without success. In the CSV there is just one single column.
Any ideas what I am doing wrong???

Comment: What are your attempts?

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're looking for...     So you want to go through each number and give it a value based on which range it falls under?  If so, what are you doing with these values?

Comment: There is a function called `filter` and another called `len` which you should look up. Try them and see if you can find a solution. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html

Comment: try `Counter(map(int, values))`

Comment: when I print out the variable spamreader I just see this:   <_csv.reader object at 0x1004e1130>

Comment: Regarding your update in which your counter variables are not incremented, that's because `csv.reader` returns rows as a list of _strings_. You need to convert them to ints _in Python_ (not in the CSV file), e.g. `if int(row[0]) in range(0,1)`. Also, how many fields are in your CSV rows? - you seem to be processing the entire row of data (which is a list!)

Comment: @ranzbert : I've updated my answer to show how to read the CSV data and convert to it to a list of floats. I've assumed that column 0 in the CSV file that contains the data.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to do it in a very concise way with [numpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/):

```
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np

with open('winter.csv') as csvfile:
    field = 0    # (zero-based) field/column number containing the required values
    float_list = [float(row[field]) for row in csv.reader(csvfile)]

#float_list = [3.13, 3.51, 3.51, 4.01, 2.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.13, 1.63, 1.88]

hist, bins = np.histogram(float_list, bins=[0,1,2,3,sys.maxint])
bin_counts = zip(bins, bins[1:], hist)  # [(bin_start, bin_end, count), ... ]

for bin_start, bin_end, count in bin_counts[:-1]:
    print '{}-{}: {}'.format(bin_start, bin_end, count)

# different output required for last bin
bin_start, bin_end, count = bin_counts[-1]
print '>{}: {}'.format(bin_start, count)
```

Which outputs:

```
0-1: 0
1-2: 5
2-3: 1
>3: 4
```

Most of the effort is in massaging the data for output.

It's also quite flexible as it is easy to use different intervals by changing the `bins` argument to `np.histogram()`, e.g. add another interval by changing `bins`:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(float_list, bins=[0,1,2,3,4,sys.maxint])
```

outputs:

```
0-1: 0
1-2: 5
2-3: 1
3-4: 3
>4: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv
a=b=c=d=0
with open('cf.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
            if 0<float(row[0])<1:
              a+=1
            elif 1<float(row[0])<2:
              b+=1
            elif 2<float(row[0])<3:
              c+=1
            if 3<float(row[0]):
              d+=1

    print "0-1:{} \n 1-2:{} \n 2-3:{} \n <3:{}".format(a,b,c,d)
```

out put:

```
0-1:0 
 1-2:5 
 2-3:1 
 <3:4
```

Because of your rows are list type we use `[0]` index to access our data and convert the string to float by `float()` function .

Comment: Using this method I am always getting this error:

print: "0-1:{} \n 1-2:{} \n 2-3:{} \n <3:{}".format(a,b,c,d)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

When I change this to "print a" it is always '0' - same with b,c,d

Comment: yes sorry ,,its a syntax error you must remove `:` after `print` i edit the answer !

Comment: Seems like it doesn't recognize the value from the CSV. If the CSV value is '1' and I only but a single if-loop like this 'if row>2: a+=1' it increments a by 1  EVEN THOUGH 1 < 2  and therefor shouldn't be counted. Does this code really work for u??

Comment: i edit the answer and i run it my self ! it works fine !

Answer (score 0):

This should do, provided the data from the CSV is in `values`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# compute a histogram
histogram = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
interval = 1.
max = 3
for v in values:
    bin = int(v / interval)
    bin = max if bin >= max else bin
    histogram[bin] += 1

# output
sum = sum(histogram.values())
for k, v in sorted(histogram.items()):
    share = 100. * v / sum
    if k >= max:
        print "{}+ : {}, {}%".format(k, v, share)
    else:
        print "{}-{}: {}, {}%".format(k, k+interval, v, share)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get the entries into a list:

```
0_to_1 = 0
1_to_2 = 0
2_to_3 = 0
ovr_3 = 0

for i in list:
     if i in range(0,1):
          0_to_1 += 1
     elif i in range (1,2):
          1_to_2 += 1
```

So on and so forth...

And to find the breakdown:

```
total_values =  0_to_1 + 1_to_2 + 2_to_3 + Ovr_3

perc_0_to_1 = (total_values/0_to_1)*100
perc_1_to_2 = (total_values/1_to_2)*100
perc_2_to_3 = (total_values/2_to_3)*100
perc_ovr_3 =  (total_values/ovr_3)*100
```

+++++ Response to Update +++++++

```
import csv

a=b=c=0
with open('winter.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        for i in row:
            i = float(i.strip()) # .strip() removes blank spaces before converting it to float
            if row in range(0,1):
                a += 1
            elif row in range(1,2):
                b += 1
            # add more elif statements here as desired.
```

Hope that works.
Side note, I like that a=b=c=o thing. Didn't realize you could do that after all this time haha.

Comment: I implemented parts of your code into mine (as it's the easiest to understand for me). But somehow I can't get it to work - pls see my update above. thx!

Comment: See my update.  (I like to keep things simple.  None of this import 4 things to sort numbers, lol)